# Control Area Network Protocol Implementation in ObjC

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to implement a CAN protocol which is used in Automobile Industry.I wanted to know if it is possible to get the CAN data packets through WiFi using NSNetService/NSNetServiceBrowser class. In Apple's Documentation, everytime they are about to describe about NSNetService/NSNetServiceBrowser
class they say "Bonjour network services" where Bonjour is a protocol implemented by apple itself.

So, I think of course it will detect those i.e Bonjour Data Packets.But now, I am not sure if it will do the same in case of CAN data packets.Hence my question is : Is CAN data packet compatible with NSNetService class so that I can use it directly? If not, is there a way to detect CAN data packets coming from a WiFi network?

Further I got a reply on Apple Developer Forum that if CAN data packets were wrapped up in some High Level Protocol like UDP then NSNetServiceBrowser class **MIGHT** read it. Now my question is if my CAN data packet was in UDP packet(lets say), is NSNetServiceBrowser class capable of detecting those data packets since NSNetServiceBrowser asks for input on service domain Name and service domain type?

Thanks in Advance.

iParag